# What are the steps for using axel-kapt in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: unity, networking

I have downloaded axel-kapt and also installed it through Ubuntu Software Center.  But now I don't know how to use axel-kapt, so please tell me how to use it with proper steps.

Comment: Take a look http://www.junauza.com/2010/04/light-and-fast-download-accelerator-for.html

Answer (score 2):

Axel-kapt is just a GUI for Axel downloader, and provides some settings for Axel. It seems to me that you want to download with Axel, and for that you should use it with [FlashGot addon in Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashgot/).
There you can set Axel as default downloader or to use it just for capturing media.

[image]

[image]