# What GUI are there for Axel or for other such downloaders that use multiple connections?

Tags: gui, download-manager, downloaders, axel

In order to enjoy my maximum download speed, I use and like Axel very much, but from time to time I download multiple files and having so many windows opened has some disadvantages.

I use Axel with FlashGot in Firefox (Seamonkey etc) but I would like to add a GUI for that, and possibly have multiple downloads in a nice list as in any civil downloader. I am not aware of a GUI for Axel that works. [Axel-kapt](http://appnr.com/package/axel-kapt) crashes. ([A question](https://askubuntu.com/q/160781/47206) on how to use it properly in Ubuntu got only one somewhat dismissive answer by yours truly...) [Gaxel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gaxel/) just opens a window with empty fields that I have to manually fill (which beats the purpose). I would like to know how to install something like [Gwget](https://projects.gnome.org/gwget/) which is described [here, in an old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/47050/47206) as an alternative (but Gwget itself might be too old too).

(So, what I ask is: multiple-connection/maximizing-speed downloader, with a GUI.)

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try flareGet.  Flareget is a full featured, multi-threaded and multi-segment download manager and accelerator.

To install click [**FlareGet** [image: Install FlareGet]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flareget/)

Or download from [Flareget](http://flareget.com/download).

The app in the Ubuntu apps directory

[image]

Ubuntu Software Center show that app.  I don't know why it shows a Buy button, but I clicked on it, put in my email and password, and it allowed me to download without paying a dime.

[image]

Here is an image of the app installed.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with it?  The OP is asking for an alternative GUI download manager.

Comment: -1 .The question alternate GUI for axel, not alternate download manager . If the questions is for alternate download manager , this is duplicate

Comment: @Tachyons - the question asks for a GUI. to what? to any download manager (including Axel) which can maximize downloads (in the way Axel does). I have checked and have not found duplicates to that

Comment: @Tachyons The OP asks to a GUI for Axel, or any GUI alternative that allows him to have multiple downloads in a nice list as in any civil downloader.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it seems that this answer answered your second part of the question, let me revert my downvote :)

Comment: BTW flareget is submitted through my apps portal, So you have to use ubuntu software center for downloading it . Ubuntu software center shows buy button, but it is free of cost :)

Comment: They do have a paid version, but also a free one.  I did click on the buy button, I could install it without paying.

Comment: It is a known bug $0 apps shows buy button. BTW paid version is not available in USC

Comment: maybe it is worth knowing that, considering the *free version* of Flareget, v.1.4 allowed a maximum of 8 connections/segments per download; in v.1.5.9 this was reduced to 4, and in v.2 to...2. equally interesting, older versions are nearly [impossible to find](http://askubuntu.com/q/340439/47206)

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try to [**uGet** [image: Install uGet]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/uget/) - a simple, lightweight and easy-to-use download manager. It provides the following features:

- Multi-Connection (aka Multi-Segment)
- Resume downloads.
- Queue downloads.
- Classify downloads in categories.
- Mozilla Firefox integration (through Flashgot plugin).
- Clipboard monitoring.
- Import downloads import from HTML files.
- Batch download. It also can be launched from the command line.

See http://ugetdm.com/features for all features. There are a lot.

[image]

Comment: i had that in mind but is it using multiple connections to maximize speed?

Comment: @cipricus Yes of course, I just edited my answer.

Comment: message from uGet team - Do NOT install uGet from the Software Center, it is ridiculously outdate in the USC for no apparent reason. You can install via DEB or PPA by going to http://ugetdm.com/downloads - uGet utilizes aria2 as a backend plugin which provides the multi-connections and much more.

Comment: uGet v.2 uses curl+aria2 and can download from multiple sources per download.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Persepolis Download Manager](https://persepolisdm.github.io/). It is a download manager & a GUI For aria2. It's written in Python. Persepolis is a Sample of Free and open source software. When i compared it to uGet it seemed faster. It  also supports browser intergration for Chromium and Firefox