# Download manager for Ubuntu 12.04 and Google Chrome

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, download-manager

I am looking for a download manager which can take over downloads in Google Chrome. I mean it must be integrate with Google Chrome.

I could not find a download assistant on Chrome Web Store. So I don't know how to integrate down managers in Google Chrome.

Comment: Try Flareget.  Have a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313087/what-gui-are-there-for-axel-or-for-other-such-downloaders-that-use-multiple-conn/313104#313104).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SteadyFlow](https://launchpad.net/steadyflow) is another option and it already has a Chrome Extension via ChromeFlow.
[image: SteadyFlow main window]

I am a member of the uGet team so I can't vouch for how well the extension or the app will work for you but it does claim to have the basics of what you want. SteadyFlow is very minimalist in function as it was meant to be just a very simple download manager, so if you want a lot of features in your Download Manager then this may not be for you but if you want just the basics with a chrome extension then this could work.

Comment: thnx, how can i install chromeflow extension using apt get?

Comment: You can't, it doesn't work like that. Go to https://launchpad.net/chromeflow and download the CRX. Then you go to your Chrome Extensions and activate Developer Mode (checkbox on extensions page)...then you drag and drop the .crx file into the window to install.

Answer (score 2):

**[uGet](http://ugetdm.com)** is the best Linux Download Manager available and works great on Ubuntu 12.04

[image: uGet Main Window and Category Context Menu]

We (uGet team) are also in the process of developing a Google Chrome/Chromium Extension that does exactly what you are requesting. The extension is still in development but we hope to release it as soon as possible.

Note* - Ubuntu Software Center has a VERY OLD version of uGet regardless the amount of effort we have put in to get it updated. So for the latest version go to http://ugetdm.com/downloads

Comment: only took 2+ years and 5 version of Ubuntu but I am glad to say that Ubuntu 14.04 will finally have an up to date version of uGet. :)

Comment: very slow speed while downlaod

Comment: that could be an issue of many factors including your connection, the server you are downloading from, the type of file being download and so on.

Comment: oh yes need to add more connection

Answer (score 1):

There is a download manager based on aria2. It uses many connections and segments. Supports resuming download.

It is under development and from time to time a lot of changes occur.

http://linuxdownloadmanager.com/