# Why can't I install gwget?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Tried installing it from command line (`sudo apt-get install gwget`)

and I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gwget is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gwget' has no installation candidate
```

what does it mean?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the package is  no longer in the repository. You either search for it online and download the .deb and install it manually, or search some third party ppa that provides the package for 13.10.
I had a look myself and doesn't seem to be one, the most similar I can find is uget and multiget, also a graphical front-end downloader, you can try them:

```
sudo apt-get install uget
sudo apt-get install multiget
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to try alternative download managers with a GUI, you can check this out:

[What GUI are there for Axel or for other such downloaders that use multiple connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313087/what-gui-are-there-for-axel-or-for-other-such-downloaders-that-use-multiple-conn/394117#394117)